# Preventing AOO during a charge

Tags: dnd-3.5e, opportunity-attack, charge

A DM ruled that a charge doesnt provoke an AOO because there is a feat that makes jump checks work like tumble. He could not come up with the name or source of the feat. And it was eventually overturned. Does a feat or any ability actually do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Charges, by default, provoke attacks of opportunity as normal for any movement. The core rules are somewhat less than explicit on this—they just say that movement usually provokes, and nothing in the charge rules says otherwise for them, so that default prevails—but *Rules Compendium* is explicit, stating that the movement for a charge provokes as normal (but the charge attack itself does not), on page 27.

Tumbling *can* avoid attacks of opportunity, but it is not automatic—the person has to succeed on a Tumble check to do it. Likewise, the existence of a feat means little for someone who does not have that feat.

Core is even more unclear whether or not Jump or Tumble can be used while charging—it simply does not say, and arguments can be made either way. *Rules Compendium* is again explicit on page 27, but now this might arguably be contradicting the core rules, which might arguably be a problem—see [this Q&A](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/37466/4563).

Anyway, as far as I am aware, the only feat that addresses attacks of opportunity while charging is Ride-by Attack, which makes it so the target does not get provoked. Everyone else still does, though. There is not, that I can find, a feat to use Jump instead of Tumble while charging—closest I can figure is Battle Jump, which lets a jump from a height count as a charge (and has numerous other benefits besides). That doesn’t affect attacks of opportunity.

Comment: You use the phrase "might arguably" twice in the same sentence, which... feels tacky.

Comment: @ObliviousSage And, based on the fact that I specifically went back and re-added it after you removed it, you might have gotten the impression that it was entirely deliberate. I want to highlight that we’ve got a debatable point on top of a debatable point here.

Comment: No mention of the feat [Leap Attack](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/38141/8610)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Despite the fluff intro about combining a charge and a leap, the feat’s benefit doesn’t seem to have anything in particular to do with charging, for all it is one of the defining feats of the Übercharger. Hence going with Battle Jump as the “closest I can figure.”